# How to open another form within a vba function and return to the function

Tags: function, vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access form with a button that calls a function that starts by checking a date and asks the user if he needs to manually change the date. If this is the case, another form is opened where the date is entered and validated. Is there a possible way to load the selected date into a variable and return to the first form into the function that is running to use it further down the procedure?

Comment: this might help you: Forms!frmBase!txtTargetBox.Value = Me.txtEntry.Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following way is working for me although I assume there is a better one.
First of all I inserted a module and declared a global variable:

```
Global globalText As String
```

Then you need to make sure the other form (here frmEntry) is called "modal", so that your code will wait until the form is closed again. You can achieve this by:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEntry", WindowMode:=acDialog
```

In frmEntry you need to write whatever value was selected then to the global variable and then close the form, which would look something like this:

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click()

    globalText = Me.txtEntry.Value
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmEntry"

End Sub
```

And then it is basically done and your code in your basic form will go on running and you can use the value from globalText anywhere or can write it to some hidden textBox to use it later in other functions.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked the first time! I didnt know about the Window Mode Switch. Thank you very much Graffl for the help

Comment: As a heads up, you likely best not close the form and just set visible = false. You THEN let the calling code grab the values from the form. This means you avoid global variables. Global vars makes code hard to read, and hard to maintain If you copy forms or code then you have an outside dependency that you also have to copy and setup.  Calling routines or forms to pass values back and forth should not rely on global variables unless simple alternatives have been exhausted.

Comment: In addition to @Albert D. Kallal: code execution returns to calling form if you state `Me.Visible = False` instead of closing the form.